I am receving error message while starting a service - for besclient
We have a below setup configured:-
BigFix version:- V10.0.11
ILMT:- V9236
We are trying to install a BigFix agent on the Linux machine – RHEL 7.9, BigFix agent version :- 10.0.10.46.
However, after we install the agent, we are receiving the below error message while starting the besclient service:-
#besclient.service failed.
#unregistered authenication agent for unix-process 26173:73633098
SELINUX is enabled and loaded policy name is Targeted.
Can anyone please assist me with it.
